# Is it possible to inject a custom JBoss module without producer method using CDI?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, module, cdi

I have a custom JBoss 7 module which provides services (for example, `EmailService` for sending e-mails). I want to use these services in applications that are deployed on the same AS.

I specified jars of the service in `module.xml` (located in `modules/jboss/module/main`).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="jboss.module">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="email-service-api.jar" />
    <resource-root path="email-service-impl.jar" />
  </resources>
</module>
```

The `email-service-api.jar` contains only interface of the service. I use this as a dependency for an implementation of the interface (in `email-service-impl.jar`) and in the applications that use the service.

In `email-service-impl.jar` there is a file named `jboss.module.EmailService` (in `META-INF/services` folder). The file contains fully qualified names of all my implementations (so far I have only one):

`jboss.module.impl.DefaultEmailService`

I would like to inject the service into an application.

Currently, I use producer method to get instance of the service from an 
application.

```
package bean;

public class Bean {

    @Inject
    EmailService emailService;

    @Produces
    public EmailService getEmailService() {
        ServiceLoader<EmailService> emailServices = ServiceLoader.load(EmailService.class);

        for (EmailService emailService : emailServices) {
            if (emailService != null) {
                return emailService;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

When I leave out the producer method I get `org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException` saying `WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [EmailService] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject bean.Bean.emailService]"}}`.

I have `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file in the application:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <deployment>
    <dependencies>
      <module name="jboss.module" services="export" />
    </dependencies>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

And I have tried to add `beans.xml` file into the "implementation-project" (i.e. `email-service-impl.jar`), but it had no effect. The exception occured anyway.

Is it possible to inject the service and omit the producer method using CDI?

Thank you,

Denis

Comment: The exception is a result of CDI attempting to 'resolve' injection points and it cannot find any bean to inject into the field.

Have you tried to verify that your producer returns anything else than `null`? E.g. that it in fact can find your implementation?

Otherwise your setup looks valid from CDI standpoint.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It works properly with the producer method; the method finds my implementation. But when I remove it, the exception is thrown.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. ATM I cannot think of another way to easily do this. But is there a reason why you do not want to use `@Produces`?

Comment: It is not that I don't want it no matter what. I would just like it more without the producer. So I tried to remove it and I failed. 
Let's say that I am fine using the producer, what is the best practice to choose between implementations (assuming that there is many of them)? Thank you for your time.

Comment: That would be easy - use qualifiers in your producers and in injection points, e.g. `@Produces @Basic` then for another impl, you would have `@Produces @ProUser` etc. The injection points would then look like this: `@Inject @ProUser EmailService`.
BTW you might even be able to move the producers into you API jar (plus add empty `beans.xml`) and it might do the work for you outside of your app code.

Comment: I am definitely going to try this, it sounds good enough to me. To the original question, do you think that there is a way to avoid producer methods and perform the injection? I mean if it is just my fault or it is impossible by principle.

Comment: Can't guarantee the correctness of my answer here, but I'd wager producers are the way to go.. The reason is that you need to load that class as a service before having it ready for injection. and since CDI is static by nature, you would need to have the services loaded before CDI boots in order to use '@Inject' w/o producers. The only other way might be with extensions which are executed as CDI boots hence might allow you to do what you need. It'd be more complex though.

Comment: I summed the above as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summing up what I wrote in the comments:

- Producers are probably a way to go here.

  - You are seeking to inject a service which you first need to load. CDI has a static nature and can only inject beans which were available during its boot time. The way around it is to use a producer.
  - To differentiate in between different implementations, you can use qualifiers. E.g. each producer and injection point will have a given qualifier (`@DefaultImpl`, `@ProUser` etc).
  - You *might* be able to put these producers in your API JAR so as not to pollute your code (plus add empty `beans.xml`).
- As for other ways apart from producers

  - I can only think of `Extension` here since they are executed as CDI boots therefore allowing you to register the implementations as beans.
  - This would make the beans available on CDI boot and therefore injectable without producers.
  - However, this approach would prove much more complex.